# How to download a file from assembla with a key and a secret using a python script

Tags: python, assembla

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.assembla.com/v1/spaces'
API_KEY = "API_KEY"
API_SECRET = "API_SECRET "
resp = requests.get(url, auth=(API_KEY, API_SECRET))
print(resp.status_code)
```

I keep getting 401. I'm not sure how to use an API_KEY and an API_SECRET to download a pdf file (let's call it test.pdf) from an assembla url given to me. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does seem like you need to use those as `headers` instead based from their [documentation](https://api-docs.assembla.cc/content/authentication.html)

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.assembla.com/v1/spaces'

headers = {
    "X-Api-Key": "API_KEY",
    "X-Api-Secret": "API_SECRET"
}

resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

See [Customer Headers](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) from the requests documentation

Comment: Thanks! That works! I fiannyl get status code 200. Now I am trying to save the file I download to resp as a pdf. I am using - 

    with open('/download/global_policy_add.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(resp.content)

But I get error no such file.

Comment: You might be looking for this: https://api-docs.assembla.cc/content/ref/documents_download.html